# Dalli Network Error with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, dalli

I am running through the below problem in my test server, where I have done memcached to site, but sometimes it throws error page. Below is description of the error. I have googled for it not getting any solution. Error:

```
Cache read: http://test.server.in/? test-cache.example.amazonaws.com:11211 failed (count: 0) RuntimeError: Cannot share client between multiple processes
 #<Dalli::NetworkError: Socket operation failed, retrying...>
retrying request with new server
Dalli::Server#connect test-cache.example.amazonaws.com:11211
```

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/dalli/blob/master/lib/dalli/server.rb#L215 here it is called    rescue SystemCallError, Timeout::Error, EOFError, SocketError => e
        # SocketError = DNS resolution failure
        failure!(e)
      end

Comment: u mean to say that DNS is not able to find ? , I dont think so connectivity is issue.

Comment: most of the chance what if `telnet`

Comment: i did telnet servername portnumber , its connecting .

Comment: did you find the problem? I'm getting something similar...